# I need to create a python function that makes an n-dimensional vector such that each element is a real number in [0,100)

Tags: python, function, vector, numerical-methods, numpy-ndarray

I'm not very good with python and I need to create a function, randvec(n), that will create an n-dimensional vector where each element is a random real number in [0,100). Below is what I have so far.

```
def randvec(n):
    vector = np.ndarray((1,n),dtype=float)
    for i in range(0,n):
        vector[i] = np.random.uniform(0,100)
        print(vector[i])

test = randvec(4)
print(test)
```

Output: [64.58722344 64.58722344 64.58722344 64.58722344]

Based on the outputs when I print inside the for loop, I don't think random.uniform() is the function I want to use because it gives me the same random number n times.

I also get this error message "index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1."

Let me know if you see my mistakes! Thanks

Comment: "it gives me the same random number n times" - no way, please post a [mcve]

Comment: I edited with the print inside the for loop and provided the output. Hope that's what you meant and that it helps

Comment: Please provide the entire error message. Why not use the appropriate NumPy function(s) for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def randvec(n):
   return [random.random()*100 for _ in range(n)]
```

will generate `n` real random values such that each value is in interval [0, 100). See class `Random` for more information on `random()` method.

But that's a PRNG (pseudo random number generator) meaning that it is predictable the "random" sequence. From Documentation:

> Warning: The pseudo-random generators of this module should not be
>   used for security purposes. Use os.urandom() or SystemRandom if you
>   require a cryptographically secure pseudo-random number generator.

For security purposes use a TRNG or CSPRNGs.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not sure why I didn't think of something this simple. Maybe not good enough for security but good enough for my math homework.